# How to union multiple CSV files with the same structure in Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am new to Cloud Data Fusion.
I want to combine two CSV files.
The two files have the same column.
In Cloud Data Fusion, I could find the "joiner" but not the union feature.
Could someone tell me how to union multiple CSV files with the same structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two CSV files have the same schema, you can union the records by connecting them both as a source to a downstream plugin.
Note that the ordering of the schemas must match as well.

[I've attached an example as a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41xLh.png).

Comment: I could union two CSV files by your advice. 
I appreciate all your help.